# Android google Play store Screenshots deformation

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to publish my first Android app on google play store and I need to give some screenshots of my app.

The problem is that when I upload the screenshots on the website, they are deformed: left side part of the image is cut off, for example, if I have a point in the center of the screen, the point will then be more on the left.

Do you know how to avoid this, or this is only a website presentation problem and on the play store, the image will be normal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the deformations and rotations you see on the publishing page are just on that page, the images will appear correctly on the play store.  (I think there's even a bit of text on that page somewhere that tells you this, maybe tucked away behind a help button)